# how do i make the program sort the numbers in a non-decreasing order and disply them from using a single JOptionpane message dialog?

Tags: java, joptionpane

```
package ex2.pkg4;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Ex24 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String num1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter The First Number");
        int no1 = Integer.parseInt(num1);
        String num2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter The Second Number");
        int no2 = Integer.parseInt(num2);
        String num3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter The Third Number");
    }
}
```

Comment: Declare three new `int` variables which will hold the numbers in order.  Use `if` statements to determine which number should be ordered first and which should be second.  Finally, create a String message containing all three ordered `int` values, using the `+` operator to include those values in the String.  Then you can display that message using JOptionPane.

Answer (score 0):

Use an Array and when the array is filled with the desired amount of numerical values use the `java.util.Arrays#sort()` method to sort that array in Ascending Order (ex: 1, 2, 3), for example:

```
/* Create a parent for your JOptionPanes. This ensures that your
   JOptionPane dialogs will not be be hidden behind possible on-top
   applications or even the IDE. This can happen if null is used as 
   parent.        */
JDialog jd = new JDialog();
jd.setAlwaysOnTop(true); jd.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    
// The number of INTEGER numerical values you want.
int desiredNumberOfValues = 3; 

// The int[] Array the will hold the valid numbers entered by User.
int[] wantedNumbers = new int[desiredNumberOfValues];

// A counter used to keep track of the number of values entered by User.
int numberCounter = 0;

// Used to hold the number entered in Input dialogs
String number;

// Get the desired amount of numbers from User...
while (numberCounter < desiredNumberOfValues) {
    numberCounter++;
    /* Notice how basic HTML is used in the Message body of the 
       Input dialog below. This can add a little flair to things :)    */
    number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(jd, "<html>Enter integer numerical value #" 
                        + " <font size='4' color= blue><b>"+ numberCounter 
                        + "</b></font>:<br><br></html>", "Integer Number Entry...", 
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    jd.dispose(); // Dispose of parent
        
    /* If a Cancel button is selected or the dialog is 
       closed, we quit.            */
    if (number == null) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jd, "<html>Application Canceled!<br><br>"
                + "<center><font size='5' color=red><b>Bye-Bye</b></font></center></html>",
                "Application Canceled" ,JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        jd.dispose(); // Dispose of parent
        return;
    }
    /* Validate the supplied value. If it's not a string representation
       of a signed or unsigned integer value then inform the User of an
       invalid entry and allow the User to try again.             */
    if (!number.matches("-?\\d+")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jd, "<html>Invalid numerical value (" + number 
                                    + ") supplied!<br>You will need to try again.</html>",
                                    "Invalid Entry...", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        jd.dispose(); // Dispose of parent
        numberCounter--; // decrement since the entry isn't valid.
        continue;  // loop again...
    }
    /* If we can get to here then the User's entry is valid 
       so we convert the entered valid number to integer and 
       then place that number into the array.     */
    wantedNumbers[numberCounter - 1] = Integer.parseInt(number);
}
    
/* Now we have all the numbers we want. Let's sort 
   them in ascending order.        */
java.util.Arrays.sort(wantedNumbers);
    
// Let's build a string to display those numbers in a message box
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
for (int val : wantedNumbers) {
    if (!sb.toString().isEmpty()) {
        sb.append(", ");
    }
    sb.append(val);
}
    
// Dsiplay all the numbers supplied by User in a Message Dialog box.
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jd, "<html>The numerical values that were supplied are:<br>"
                            + "<br><center><font size='5' color=blue><b>" + sb.toString() 
                            + "</b></font></center></html>", "Supplied Values..."
                            ,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
jd.dispose(); // Dispose of parent
```